# What is the definition of a thread safe function according to the C++11 (Language/Library) Standard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

**TL;DR**: What is meant by saying a *specific* function is 'thread-safe' as a data race occurs by simultaneously calling two *possibly different* functions? This question is especially relevant in the context of people telling "*const means/implies thread-safe in C++11*" [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11)[[2]](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/you-dont-know-const-and-mutable-herb-sutter)

---

Consider the following example:

```
class X {
    int x, y; // are some more complex type (not supported by `std::atomic`)
    std::mutex m;
public:
    void set_x (int new_x) {x = new_x;} // no mutex
    void get_x () const {return x;}

    void set_y (int new_y) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m); // guard setter with mutex
        y = new_y;
    }
    void get_y () const {return y;}
}
```

**Is `set_x` thread safe?**

Off course, `set_x` is not thread safe as calling it from two threads simultaneously results in a data race.

**Are `get_x`, `get_y` and `set_y` thread safe?**

Two possible reasonings exists:

1. Yes, they are thread safe, as calling `get_x`/`get_y`/`set_y` from two threads simultaneously does not result in a data race.
2. No, they are not thread safe, as calling `get_x` (or `get_y`) and `set_x` (or `set_y`) from two threads simultaneously results in a data race.

Which one is the correct reasoning for each of those three functions?

---

### Question summary

Which reasoning is correct?

1. A function is thread safe iff calling it from two threads simultaneously does not result in a data race. Could work for `set_x`/`get_x`, but fails for `set_y`/`get_y`, as this would result to the conclusion that `set_y` and `get_y` are thread safe, but class `Y` isn't as calling `set_y` and `get_y` from two threads simultaneously results in a data race.
2. A function is thread safe iff it does not access any memory that could be modified without internal synchronization by another function. This seems to me the most consistent option, but is not the way it is often used (see related threads).

---

### Related threads

Note that I have read the following related threads:

- [Does const mean thread-safe in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11) ['mean' = it's your duty to make it]
- [How do I make a function thread safe in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410916/how-do-i-make-a-function-thread-safe-in-c)
- https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/you-dont-know-const-and-mutable-herb-sutter
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/379516/is-the-meaning-of-const-still-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: Consider `std::atomic<int> x;` instead of `int x;` for the thread safe implementation.

Comment: @RichardCritten, you are absolutely right, but it will not be enough to ensure thread safety. The method used to manipulate the shared variable x must be in a synchronized way.

Comment: @ManifestMan, why isn't it enough for thread safety?

Comment: @RichardCritten, you are right, but that solution does not work for more complex types, maybe I should edit my example to use a more complex data member such as `std::string`.

Comment: @RichardCritten, in addition to the definition of atomic variable through **std::atomic<int> x** proper atomic load/store are also needed.

Comment: @ManifestMan please explain and see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D

Comment: @Richard Critten, the provided link says about **std::atomic<T>::load - Atomically loads and returns the current value of the atomic variable. Memory is affected according to the value of order.**, but the user should better use `std::memory_order_seq_cst`  for ordering  while calling those functions (consistency reasons). Because so many things can go wrong there.

Comment: @ManifestMan The default memory ordering value is `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for both methods `std::atomic<T>::load` and `std::atomic<T>::store`. There's no need to add unnecessary clutter to the code. Deep down, `std::atomic` fulfills its purpose by behaving like a fence / barrier on two different levels: on the compiler level, memory operations aren't reordered across the barrier; on the machine instruction level, the necessary architectural memory barrier instructions are issued, depending on the CPU architecture and the `std::atomic` method called. (cont'd...)

Comment: @ManifestMan (...cont'd) Note that the design of `std::atomic` appears to facilitate its use as a semaphore; that is, a flag variable that is to be set by one core after **some other data** had been written completely (by that writer-core); and a flag variable that is to be checked by other cores before commencing a read operation on **that other data**. As far as x86 and ARM are concerned, the current C++ library implementation for `std::atomic` is adequate for guaranteeing correct operation, even if **those other data** aren't written or read using special methods. (cont'd...)

Comment: @ManifestMan (...cont'd) However, users of GCC will have an additional issue requiring attention - "strict aliasing". GCC is permitted to manipulate memory operations on the advice of its string aliasing analysis; this may affect memory operations, i.e. operations on **those other data** which are typical in C++ and without using special instructions. Examples of such compiler manipulation are: eliminating reads or writes, or replacing them with no-op or constant value, if GCC **believes** that the memory location isn't properly initialized or is never read back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note that this my own opinionated answer based on my own research and provided input from others.*

### What is the definition of a thread-safe function?

A function is thread safe iff it does not access (read or write) any memory that could be modified without internal synchronization: only `set_y` is thread-safe.

Note that thread-safe is not explicitly defined by the C++ standard, which uses the term data races. See the answer of Nicol Bolas for more information: thread-safety is not always black and white.

### A const function implies <strike>thread-safe</strike> bitwise const **or** internally synchronised

The term *thread-safe* is abused in the context of "*a const function implies thread-safe*".

What is meant by "*a const function implies thread-safe*", is that it should be safe to call the const function from multiple threads (**without** calling a non-const function at the same time in another thread).

As [Herb Sutter](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) (29:43) stated himself, in this context, thread-safe means bitwise const **or** internally synchronised, which isn't really thread-safe if other non-const functions may be called at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard doesn't use terms like "thread-safe"; it uses more specific language. Humans use terms like "thread-safe" because we find them useful.

The common idea of a thread-safe function is a function that when called, *assuming nobody else screws up*, will not create a data race. `get_x` is thread-safe; all things being equal, you may call it from any number of threads and get reasonable results. This is true even though it cannot be concurrently called with `set_x`, as that causes a data race. But the cause of the data race is that you called a non-thread-safe function: `set_x`.

The point of categorizing functions as "thread-safe" or not is to assign blame. If you call only "thread-safe" functions, then your code is "thread-safe". If you stray outside of the boundaries of "thread-safe" functions, then it is your straying outside of those boundaries that causes the data race.

It's not `get_x`'s fault that a concurrent `set_x` call causes a data race.

As for the question of `get/set_y`, as previously stated, "thread-safe" is not a *computational* term or a rigorously standard term. It is a human term, a simplification of the computational reality.

The rules of what is "thread-safe" is basically, "you can call any thread-safe function concurrently with any other thread-safe function". If you cannot call `get_y` and `set_y` concurrently, then they're not "thread-safe".

From a rigorous perspective, the accurate way to describe these two functions is that `set_y` synchronizes with other calls to `set_y` on the same object, and `get_y` synchronizes with other calls to `get_y` on the same object. The fact that we don't also say that they synchronize with each other tells you what you need to know.

From a simplified perspective, `set_y` is "thread-safe"; `get_y` is not. But you could also say that `get_y` is "thread-safe" and `set_y` is not. It doesn't really matter, since it's just a simplification.

And whether you declare `get_y` `const` is not what makes it "thread-safe". Sutter is saying that, if you write a `const` function, it is *your job* to do it in a way such that it is "thread-safe". Therefore, `get_y` is broken because it is not written in a thread-safe way, since it cannot be called thread-safely with other thread-safe functions.

Comment: I'm aware it is my duty to make a const function bitwise const or internally synchronised. That's way I used the term implies.

Comment: Is it correctly to say that `get_y` is broken according to the C++11 standard? If I interpret it correctly, it's only telling us that calling only const function should be thread safe.

Comment: @m7913d: "*Is it correctly to say that get_y is broken according to the C++11 standard?*" There is no requirement on the user to write a function that is "thread-safe". Only a requirement not to write a *program* which does not introduce a data race.

Comment: So, what do you mean by `get_y` is broken? It's broken according to the human interpretation of thread safe or it is broken according to the C++ standard as it introduces a data race?

Comment: I agree, that I should have written (to avoid any confusion): "If I interpret it correctly, it's only telling us that calling only const function should not introduce data races."

Comment: @m7913d: "*So, what do you mean by get_y is broken?*" Read the sentence in context. In particular, take note of the sentence right before that one.

Comment: I'm confused by that context as Sutter made this statement in the context of the C++11 standard, but I believe `get_y` does not violate the C++11 standard as it is a bitwise const function (so no data race is introduced by calling this function and other well-behaving const functions). Sutter uses the term thread-safe in this context for bitwise const or internally synchronised. However, you are saying it doesn't matter wether you call `set_y` or `get_y` thread-safe as it is a simplification. This makes the statement of Sutter meaningless or is at least a confusing usage of thread-safe.

Comment: @m7913d: Sutter is making two points. He is talking about how the standard library treats `const`, *and* he is making the case that this is *also* how users should treat `const`. One of these is definitive, the other is suggestive. The standard can enforce this on its own types, and the standard library will *assume* this for any types you give it to manipulate, but it has no say about how you treat your own types.

Comment: @m7913d: Let me put it this way. Whether Herb Sutter would call either of the `y` functions "thread-safe" is not nearly as important as what a user will try to do with that information. And if you tell a user that both of those functions are "thread-safe", they will *definitely* feel that it is OK to call either of them on the same object from any thread. And their code will *definitely* be broken. So are they thread-safe? Not in a way that's actually useful to people.

Comment: But Sutter's point is that almost all classes will be used sooner or later (by you or someone else later on) inside the C++ standard library (f.ex a container class). So, you better make it compatible with it). As stated in the title, I want to be compatible with the C++ standard library and language. (Note that I did quite some research on this topic, before asking the question).

Comment: I think it is relevant wether it is correct to use thread-safe in this case, because if it isn't, we (nor Herb Sutter) should use it in this context as it is confusing and meaningless.

Comment: Do you agree `get_y` complies with the assumptions of the standard library?

Comment: @m7913d: "*But Sutter's point is that almost all classes will be used sooner or later (by you or someone else later on) inside the C++ standard library (f.ex a container class).*" Unless the container class is actually *calling* those functions, their behavior is irrelevant.

Comment: @m7913d: "*Do you agree `get_y` complies with the assumptions of the standard library?*" I don't see that it matters. `get/set_y` are dysfunctional with regard to how they are *intended* to work, in terms of what the writer of the code clearly *expects* to get out of them. The fact that `set_y` synchronizes access to the member strongly implies that access to `y` is meant to be fully synchronized. But it isn't. What the standard library may or may not do is irrelevant next to the fact that the code is incoherent.

Answer (score 0):

I'll also go with the your following statement:

> A function is thread safe if it does not access any memory that could be modified without internal synchronization by another function. This seems to me the most consistent option, but is not the way it is often used.

As long as the shared variable is atomic and mutex are properly used to achieve synchronization, I don't see any problem with your above statement.

Comment: The problem is that the related threads seems to use the first definition for 'thread safe function'. And those guys seems to be highly familiar with the C++ standard especially Herb Sutter (see last related thread).

Comment: Are you able to back up this statement with some official documentation (from the C++ Language/Library standard)?

Comment: Just take a look [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races)

Comment: That doesn't answer what is meant with a 'thread safe function'. Note that my question is not about how to determine whether a data race (could) occur, but about the terminology of a 'thread safe function'

Comment: I would recommand to read following post about **Thread Safety** in this case [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-thread-safe).

Comment: I know what thread safety means (no data races), but I'm confused by people stating a single function is thread safe, f.ex. [because it only reads data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6411001/7621674). Off course the program as a whole is not thread safe if a non-synchronised setter exists. The meaning of a thread safe function is especially relevant if one states that [const functions implies thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14127380/7621674).

Comment: @m7913d It's the data that needs to be protected; functions are a distraction to the discussion.  Any code-path (not any function) through a program that can simultaneously read/write (or write/write) the same location needs to be synchronised.

Comment: @RichardCritten, I agree. Does that mean that stating '_const (functions) implies thread safe_' is nonsense?