# Why use thread_local inside functions?

Tags: c++

I thought functions are thread safe if they don't modify non-local data.

My assumption is correct according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6411001/14659574). But, recently I came across this code,

```
int intRand(const int & min, const int & max) {
    static thread_local std::mt19937 generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min,max);
    return distribution(generator);
}
```

The code left me puzzled. Why does it use `thread_local` if functions are already thread safe?

Comment: `distribution(generator)` changes `generator`. If it was just `static` then multiple threads calling `intRand` would modify the same object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It does but distribution is initialized locally.

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that `distribution` modifies `generator`.  If multiple threads call the function at the same, they will all modify `generator` at the same time, which is a data race.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh! I didn't know much about static's inner workings so it creating a variable that's life time ends only after program end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The random number generators of the standard library (including the `std::mt19937` used in the example) may not be used unsequenced in multiple threads. `thread_local` guarantees that each thread has their own generator which makes it possible to call the function unsequenced from multiple threads.

> I thought functions are thread safe if they don't modify non-local data.

Static storage is non-local. This is true even when the variable with static storage duration is a local variable. The name is local; the storage is global.

Answer (score 2):

This is for clarity only.

```
static thread_local std::mt19937 generator;
```

and

```
thread_local std::mt19937 generator;
```

are the same things.

The `static` is cosmetic in this case. Both are `static`.